# laravel relation with information

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have products table and countries table, they suppose to be in a many to many relation to each other but to contain additional parameter for the relation.

so in the products there is the product id, name

in the countries there is the country id, name

in the product_country there is country_id, product_id, price

product model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Product extends Model
{
    /**
    * Get the countries for the product.
    */
    public function countries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Country');
    }

}
```

country model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Country extends Model
{
    /**
    * Get the countries for the product.
    */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product');
    }

}
```

so i know i can use
     ->withPivot('price')
to add it to the pivot relation but what i can't figure out - is what is the best way to query the list of products for example by country, maybe my structure is wrong but i would like eventually to be able to get all the products with their prices of course for a specific country.

it feels like i need to do so much work to get a price for a product by country.

```
Country::find(1)->products->first()->pivot->price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first change this relationship function into Country.php

```
 public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'pivot_table_name','country_id','product_id')->withPivot('price','sku');
    }
```

and then try this query.

```
 $countries = Country::with(['products'])->get();
```

> if you want to pass parameter then use this query

```
 $countries = Country::with([
                'products' => function ($query) use ($productId) {
                    $query->where('id', $productId);
                }
            ])->where('id', $countryId)->first();
```

Comment: yeah, my example works and it's exactly the same as you did, i didn't say it doesn't i just want to make it easier and smarter. so that is what i said i know i can do, it's not what i want to do though.. what i'm aiming for is: giving a product _id and a country_id -> get the product with all his parameters.., it's not just price, it's shipping, currency, sku, etc... i want to be able to do an "inner join" of the products table with the product country table so i'll get from products -> id, name, price, shipping, etc.. by a country id.

Comment: @ShahafAntwarg you pass multiple column in relationship function. like withPivot('column1', 'column2');